# How to perform 'sed' operation between start and end time among multiple logs in case of log rollover.?

Tags: linux, bash

$`ls -lrt test*log*`

```
-rwxr----- 1 root xyzgroup 54231265 Sep  4 16:06 test.log.9
-rwxr----- 1 root xyzgroup 53990979 Sep  4 16:06 test.log.8
-rwxr----- 1 root xyzgroup 53372511 Sep  4 16:06 test.log.7
```

$`cat test.log.9|head -5`

```
Sep  4 12:59:01.701796 <sometext>
Sep  4 12:59:01.701796 <sometext>
Sep  4 12:59:01.720171 <sometext>
Sep  4 12:59:01.720171 <sometext>
Sep  4 12:59:01.720699 <sometext>
```

$`cat test.log.9|tail -5`

```
Sep  4 13:16:01.880489 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.880489 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.880489 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.880489 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.880489 <sometext>
```

$`cat test.log.8|head -5`

```
Sep  4 13:16:01.898749 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.898749 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.898749 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.898948 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:16:01.898948 <sometext>
```

$`cat test.log.8|tail -5`

```
Sep  4 13:35:02.513804 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:35:02.513804 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:35:02.513804 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:35:02.514136 <sometext>
Sep  4 13:35:02.514136 <sometext>
```

**Log format at the beginning of each line:**

**Command:**

`sed -rn '/Sep  4 09:38:*/,/Sep  4 11:23:*/p' test*log* > temp_test.log`

**Observation:**
When performing sed operation on the listed files, required log content between start and end time is not fetched. Instead it will fetch partial log lines or sometime the output file size increases(in GB). Also some time for shorter duration log lines are properly fetched.

**Expected:**
Log lines between start and end time stamps.

---

Edit on behalf of the OP after reverting:

When trying the solution in [bodo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63739694/10622916) as a remote command using `ssh`, an error occurs:

```
local machine$ sudo ssh user@1.2.3.4 "sudo sed -rn '/Sep 4 09:38:*/,/Sep 4 11:23:*/p' $(ls -vr /user/xyz/test*log*)" > temp_test.log

ls: cannot access /user/xyz/test*log*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the contents of a few example input files, the exact command you use and the actual and expected resulting from this input. The `sed` command (in the 1st version of the question) seems to read from stdin, not from the files shown in the question. Hint: Maybe it is a sorting issue. The order of the files as passed to a command may not be what you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately it is too late to edit the error in my previous comment. I meant "...and the actual and expected output resulting from this input." The pattern `/Sep  4 09:38:*/` does not mean `Sep  4 09:38:` followed by anything (as you might expect) but `Sep  4 09:38` followed by any number of colons (`:`) including 0. You probably mean `/Sep  4 09:38:.*/`. If you want to find this pattern at the beginning of the line only, you should anchor it using `^`. Otherwise it may match a line that contains this pattern anywhere. In this case you can omit the trailing `.*`, i.e. `/^Sep  4 09:38:/`.

Comment: Please show example input files that will reproduce the problem. Please specify which shell you use. (bash ?, zsh ?, ...)

Comment: Its Bash. Also i have updated the log contents in the question. In the above logs, im searching between the timestamp. In this case log is fetched till "Sep  4 13:16:01.880489" of the first log test.log.9.

Comment: Your input files are still not clear. Instead of showing a few lines of big real log files, create a few sample files with a few lines each that can be used to reproduce the problem. Show the actual and expected output matching your example files. (If necessary to reproduce different problems, you can provide more than one example.) See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Command given by you in the Answer section works fine if i run in the machine where logs are present. But i want to run the same command from another machine to get the logs from remote machine where the actual logs are present.

Comment: Please, never replace the original question with a modified question as the answer will no longer match the question. **Add** the new requirement and state that you added it after finding problems with my answer. (Other users may add answers later.) You should revert the modification of version 5.

Comment: Sorry, it is first time for me.

Comment: If you need help I could revert the change for you.

Comment: Yes please. you can revert.

Comment: I tried to add what you intended to ask. Please check if the command is exactly as you tried it on your system. Fix it if necessary. Do you really need `sudo` locally to execute `ssh`?

Comment: Thanks for reverting. Yes, sudo is required in my case.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify **why** you need the `sudo` both on the local machine and on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is caused only by the order of the input files as passed to `sed` you can use the sorting option `-v` of the `ls` command (in your specific use case).

> `-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text`

Compare

```
echo test.log*
echo $(ls -vr test.log*)
```

In your specific case you can try

```
sed -rn '/Sep  4 09:38:*/,/Sep  4 11:23:*/p' $(ls -vr test.log*) > temp_test.log
```

**Note: This solution will not work in all cases.**
It requires that the file names resulting from the pattern `test*log*` do not contain any whitespace or special characters. The file names shown in the question fulfill this requirement.

In general, performing word splitting to extract file names from command output is problematic and should be avoided.

Without knowing the contents of the input files it is impossible to check if there are other causes that could lead to the problems described in the question.

---

Answer for additional question about remote execution:

The command

```
sudo ssh user@1.2.3.4 "sudo sed -rn '/Sep 4 09:38:*/,/Sep 4 11:23:*/p' $(ls -vr /user/xyz/test*log*)" > temp_test.log
```

does not work because `ls -vr /user/xyz/test*log*` is run on the local machine.

You can try quoting to get this part executed on the remote machine, but this can get complicated.

I suggest to create a shell script on the remote machine, e.g. `/home/user/logfilter`

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# lt 2 ]
then
   echo "usage: logfilter from to" >&2
   exit 1
fi

from="$1"
to="$2"
sed -rn "/^$from/,/^$to/p" $(ls -vr /user/xyz/test*log*)
```

and run it like this

```
sudo ssh user@1.2.3.4 "sudo ./logfilter 'Sep 4 09:38:' 'Sep 4 11:23:'" > temp_test.log
```

(untested)

Comment: Thanks for the command, it works perfectly when I run it in local machine where the logs are present. My requirement is, if I try to run this command from local machine to get the log from remote machine, ls command is giving me an error.

local machine$ sudo ssh user@1.2.3.4 "sudo sed -rn '/Sep  4 09:38:*/,/Sep  4 11:23:*/p' $(ls -vr /user/xyz/test*log*)" > temp_test.log

Getting below error:
ls: cannot access /user/xyz/test*log*: No such file or directory

Comment: @Ajay Please don't write additional requirements in a comment. Add it to the question instead. It is difficult to read code in a comment unless it is very short and correctly formatted. The command `ls -vr /user/xyz/testlog` and the output redirection are executed on the local machine.